# Animate spinning wheel with cubic-bezier in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael, physics

I've constructed a "wheel of fortune" using Raphael.js and now wish to animate this wheel to some arbitrary degree of rotation. I perform this animation using Raphael.js's [animate function](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate):

```
degrees += 360;
var duration = 1000;

wheel.animate({transform:"r"+degrees+" 250 250"},duration,"cubic-bezier(0,0,1,1)",null);
```

In this snippet I've specified a constant duration and a linear cubic-bezier which is nothing like the real spin of a wheel. Given some change in rotation how can I best animate this change so as to model the physics of a wheel being spun and then friction bringing the wheel to a stop at the final degree of rotation?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for different constants to pass to your `cubic-bezier` function, I'd recommend taking a look at [cubic-bezier.com](//cubic-bezier.com), which lets you play around with different combination of curves. The site itself only applies the function to linear movement (not rotation), but it should give you a nice starting point to tinker with some different values.